# What happens when I clone a struct with Arc inside?

Tags: rust, thread-safety, automatic-ref-counting

I would like to know what happens when I clone a `struct` that has properties inside of `Arc`.

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Foo {
  bar: Arc<String>
}
```

When I call `clone` on `Foo`, what happens? Is it safe to share the `Foo` struct between threads and use the underlying `Arc` or should I do something like this?

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Foo
where
    Foo: Sync + Send,
{
    bar: Arc<String>,
}
```

I'm essentially just trying to nest a bunch of structs into one so I can more easily share them with different things. Would it make more sense to have the wrapper struct as an `Arc` and unwrap the properties? I can provide more context if necessary but wanted to keep it abstract for now.

I've used a non-grouped up version of all my Arcs directly in the places I needed them which is also fine but cumbersome. I'm not really sure how to test this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what's unclear in the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html#derivable).

> This trait can be used with #[derive] if all fields are Clone. The derived implementation of Clone calls clone on each field.
>
> For a generic struct, #[derive] implements Clone conditionally by adding bound Clone on generic parameters.

From the [docs on `Send`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Send.html#impl-Send-for-Arc%3CT%3E) you can see `Arc<T>` is `Send` if its content is `Sync + Send`

If you better wrap each field separately or the whole struct in an `Arc` depends on your usecase but usually every `Arc` comes with overhead so the fewer the better.

Comment: I'm a bit new to Rust - sorry. So all the properties are cloned but is Foo safe for usage between threads? If two threads access a property that is thread safe inside of it is that okay?

Comment: Well yes, that's made safe by `Sync` + the borrow checker rules: two threads can only read from the object, which is safe by virtue of the object being `Sync`.